# How can I save character customizations in Saints Row IV?

Tags: pc, saints-row-iv

In Saints Row IV, I've noticed that I can save outfits by going to Wardrobe -> Outfits -> Save Outfit. Is there a way that I can do the same for character customizations?

I'd like to be able to do this without being required to upload them to the Saints Row community (in part because that hasn't been working for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a built-in way to save character customizations. However, it is possible to manually extract a character from a save file.

To extract a character from a save file:

1. Open the save file in a hex editor.
2. Go to offset `0x5b80`.
3. Select an additional `0x2268` bytes. (The selection will end at `0x7de8`.)
4. Copy the selected bytes and save them in a new file.

To insert an extracted character into an existing save file:

1. Open the save file and the extracted character file in a hex editor.
2. Copy the bytes of your extracted character.
3. Go to offset `0x5b80` in your save file.
4. Select an additional `0x2268` bytes in your save file. (The selection will end at `0x7de8`.)
5. Paste your extracted character, overwriting the current character.

[This forum posting](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/saving-characters-to-a-file-for-personal-storage.495/) got me started. However, the offset of `0x2264` given by [AZInuYasha](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/members/azinuyasha.15716/) does not include the pitch of your character's voice, but extending it to `0x2268` does.